# How to Insert a line in a file before a string match in Groovy

Tags: file, groovy

Im trying to read a text file find a specific text in a line and if match add a new line before the found line

So if I have a text file with

> This is a test string for issue @12345

Then I can search for @12345 and add something before like

> @review
>
> This is a test string for issue @12345

I try with this example but only can add lines after the match

```
def file = new File('test.txt')
def raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, 'rw')

def line = raf.readLine()
while (!line.contains("@12345")) {
  line = raf.readLine()
}

raf.writeBytes('@Review')
raf.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you are asking a question about Groovy, there is no point in attracting Java experts with the [tag:java] tag.  We have removed it for you.

Comment: Consider reading a groovy book. Groovy has more options to handle files -  For example file.text will get all the text.  or readLines.   See some example at http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-files.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest a solution that writes to a file that is being processed at the same time. Instead, you might apply a very simple and straightforward approach - write an expected content to a temporary file and if you have to override the input file, move the new temp file to the old one.

Consider the following example:

```groovy
import com.google.common.io.Files

def oldFile = new File('test.txt')
def newFile = File.createTempFile("test", UUID.randomUUID().toString())

newFile.withWriter { output ->
  oldFile.eachLine { line ->
    if (line.contains("@12345")) {
      output.write("@Review\n")
    }
    output.write(line)
    output.write("\n")
  }
}

Files.move(newFile, oldFile)
```

Here we create a new temporary file and we read from the input file and put contents to the new file. When we spot `@12345`, we prepend the line with a new line containing `@Review`. In the end, we call `Files.move(newFile, oldFile)` and this method handles moving content from one file to another, and it removes the temporary file we used in this approach.

Running this example with `test.txt` file like this one:

```
lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
This is a test string for issue @12345
something else
```

produces following updated `test.txt` file:

```
lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet
@Review
This is a test string for issue @12345
something else
```

Comment: As an optimisation (massively premature) I'd use `withWriter` instead of using `<<` to write to the file. `<<` is awesome for small files, but gets increasingly slower the larger the file it's writing to

Comment: Hi @tim_yates! Thanks for the good suggestion! :) Updated the answer to follow your advice.